# Can't cast 'const void *' to 'struct struct_name*'

Tags: c, casting

I tried to cast `const void*` to `struct struct_name*` in the following code:

```c
int struct_cmp (const void *a, const void *b) {
    return (struct struct_name*)a->number-(struct struct_name*)b->number;
}
```

But the cast does not work and the compiler return **error: request for member ‘number’ in something not a structure or union**
Could anyone please explain why it does not work and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's the right syntax:

```
((struct struct_name*)a)->number
```

And as @Zan pointed, you're missing a * in b.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot your second pointer dereference on `b`.

Comment: Oh sorry that's my typo when posting this question, I have the '*' for b in my code but it does not work

Comment: I checked the duplicated question, that perfectly solve my question, thank you